# Error al actualizar Android Studio Dolphin:

Tags: android-studio, plugin

Al actualizar Android Studio Dolphin obtengo el error:

Plugin error: Plugin 'JetBrains Marketplace Licensing Support' (version '221.6008.18') is not compatible with the current version of the IDE, because it requires build 221.6008 or newer but the current build is AI-213.7172.25

Comment: ¿Qué versión de android studio usabas anteriormente?

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error indica:

> El plugin 'JetBrains Marketplace Licensing Support' (versión
> '221.6008.18') no es compatible con la versión actual del IDE, porque
> requiere la compilación 221.6008 o posterior, pero la compilación
> actual es AI-213.7172.25

Revisando la documentación del plugin ["JetBrains Marketplace Licensing Support"](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13407-jetbrains-marketplace-licensing-support/versions), la versión '221.6008.18' es soportada por:

```
 Android Studio — Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 — Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2
```

Por esta razón debes [actualizar](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update?hl=es-419#channels) Android Studio Dolphin a [Android Android Studio — Electric Eel | 2022.1.1](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2023/02/android-studio-electric-eel-202211.html), ya que esta versión soporta el plugin 'JetBrains Marketplace Licensing Support' (versión '221.6008.18').